# Android don't want to see the OptionMenu

Tags: android, button, menu

I have added a button in the action bar, it works fine but if I press the physical menu button, the menu appears action_settings. Instead I want to use only the menu in the ActionBar and not that of the physical menu button.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scegli, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.add_c:
            Intent intent = null;
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Inserisci_.class); 
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

                case R.id.action_settings:
                return false;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overriding `onKeyDown` method in your activity and returning `true` if the *menu* key was pressed - this will effectively prevent android from internally handling the *menu* key:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my editor makes me remove `@Override`, and then does not work. 
Maybe I'm wrong something? I included this in my OnCreateView: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: What version of android are you targeting?

Comment: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: Hm... Activity _does_ have `onKeyDown` method, therefore `@override` should work.  You are putting this into the activity, aren't you?

Comment: No, sorry, this is in the Fragment!

Comment: Ah! Of course it won't work then.  You have to put this into the activity class.

Comment: I'm using the NavigationDrawer with the Fragment. How do I view each fragment to a different action bar menu?

Comment: @user2847219 This seems to be a completely different question from what you asked originally